# Particle Swarm Optimization in C++

Tags: c++, particle-swarm

I need to implement the PSO algorithm in C++. Is there any C++ library I can use to start with?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Particleswarm.info](http://www.particleswarm.info/) hosts a good [PSO toolbox repository](http://www.particleswarm.info/Programs.html).

Comment: is there any discrete PSO library somewhere?